# Обращение к массиву через переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив `massiv_228`, и к нему нужно обратиться через другую переменную `massiv` (я в нее передаю уникальный ID). Я понимаю, что делаю неправильно, но не пойму как исправить.

Вот пример кода:

```
// Массив
var massiv_228 = [
    '44',
    '45',
    '49',
    '50',
    '51',
];

var ID = '228';
var massiv = 'massiv_' + ID;

$(massiv).each(function() {
    // Элементы массива
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плохой способ, но кажется, что по-другому строку не превратить в имя локальной переменной:

```js
~function () {
  var massiv_228 = ['44', '45', '49', '50', '51'];

  var ID = '228';
  var massiv = eval('massiv_' + ID);

  console.log(massiv);
}()
```

По-хорошему надо пересмотреть подход и скаладывать массивы внутрь:

```js
~function () {
  var data = { 228: ['44', '45', '49', '50', '51'] };

  var ID = '228';
  var arr = data[ID];

  console.log(arr);
}()
```

Comment: Шикарно, основная проблема была в eval(). Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо бы слово "Плохой" выделить жирным и добавил пометку "никогда не повторяйте этого дома" :)

Answer (score 4):

Вы объявили массив глобально, так что можно получить его как свойство глобального объекта:

```js
// Массив
var massiv_228 = [
    '44',
    '45',
    '49',
    '50',
    '51',
];

var ID = '228';
var massiv = 'massiv_' + ID;
console.log(window[massiv]);
```

Comment: В консоли: undefined

Comment: @L3n1n, потому что так только с глобальными переменными можно.

Comment: Я не понял, чем мне это должно помочь?

Comment: @L3n1n в ответе представлен пример как это можно сделать с глобальными переменными. Если у вас `massiv_228` - глобальная переменная, то это решение вам поможет. Если нет - стоит использовать нормальное решение вместо кучи переменных `massiv_X`.